# Determining when an equality holds, based on proven inequality.

Tags: inequality

I am working on the same question as a poster [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16742) and I was able to prove the inequality by re-factoring to:

$$ (x-z)^2 + 4y(2-x-z) + 4y^2 \geq 0$$

and arguing that given the conditions, this holds (first and third terms are positive, for the second $y>0$ by definition and so is $2-x-z$).

However, I am also asked to determine when the **equality** holds. Given that I have a sum, I don't see a way to do that:

$$ (x-z)^2 + 4y(2-x-z) + 4y^2 = 0$$

Can someone explain the general direction I should move in to be able to prove the equality? The only bright thought was dividing by $4y$ and looking for a substitution, but this did not yield anything.

Comment: @J.M., thanks for the edit, I was just searching through help how to make the formulas appear properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just argued that all term are non-negative real numbers, yes?  Ergo, their sum must be strictly positive if any are strictly positive.  So $y=0$ and $x=z$ is a necessary and sufficent condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you get each term to equal zero, then the entire thing will equal zero.  If we have that $y=0$ and $x-z=0$, then equality will hold.  Then equality holds when $y=x-z=0$.  There should be other conditions for which equality holds, but this is one.